# parse partial html string with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `$.ajax()` to get some HTML pages from my server. 
The retrun contains the full HTML result. But i am only interested in a very specific div inside this document.

The only given thing is that my ajax success function returns a JSON object. I have made a PHP proxy file i use for other stuff that returns me a JSON object with the headers, some information to the file I'm loading and its contents. So basically i have a string containing the whole HTML of the page.

Actually i make it like that: `$($(data.content)[21])`
but this is awful example of jquery (Because i use the $ selector twice, and the HTML could by changing and the div I'm interested in could be changing position in the jquery array). I would like to get only the div `<div id="items">...</div>` and its contents and only then select it with jquery.

What is the best practice for this case? What would your approach look like?

PS: in case that my example is not clear, your can see an example here:
http://meodai.ch/content_slider/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
success: function(result) {
    var div = $(result).filter('#items');
}
```

Comment: I have done this first, but then figured it would be kind a waste of resources to select the whole result with jquery and only then look for #items. Is it slower to extract the div from the string first and then select it with jquery?

Comment: In terms of performance the best would be to have your php script return directly the partial HTML you need.

Comment: Good idea, would you regexp it? or is there some class to easily browse the DOM of a HTML file in PHP? phpQuery ? :P

Comment: No, no regexp, just separate the HTML fragment you need into another script.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var $items = $(data.content).find('#items')
```

or if `#items` is at the top level of the `<body>`, then do this instead:

```
var $items = $(data.content).filter('#items')
```

- http://api.jquery.com/find/
- http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: great i was thinking but you push it faster a bit great , you are up once!

Answer (score 1):

Once you parse the JSON response and get the HTML out of it, wrap it in a jQuery object:

```
var $j = $(htmlGoesHere);
```

Then, extract the HTML of the div:

```
var itemsHTML = $j.find("#items").html();
```